# How to debug script-fu scripts for gimp in scheme?

Tags: debugging, scheme, gimp, script-fu

I try to make some script for gimp, using script-fu, scheme.

Naturally, as a beginner, there are lots of errors and misunderstandings.

Now I'm looking for a way to debug those scripts.

I found (gimp-message), but the result does not show up. I'm not aware if there is a possibility to print debug messages to anywhere I could check them.

Generating new images filled with text would probably work ;-) but looks a bit like an overkill.

What ways to debug a script in gimp are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of gimp-message goes to the "Error console" (if you have this dockable dialog setup), otherwise in a warning dialog.

If you are in Linux or OSX, you can also start Gimp from a terminal and use `(print ...)` calls, they will show in the terminal.

You can make your life easier and write your scripts in Python (easier to learn, and more powerful...).  See [here](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) for the doc, [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) for some examples, and [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows) for some debug tricks for Windows.

Comment: with (print) the output doesn't go to the console where gimp has been started but to a pop-up and that's slightly more convenient for small texts.

Comment: Possibly OS dependent. Are you on Windows, OSX or some Linux/Unix?

Comment: I'm on Linux, with gimp 2.6.6.

Comment: Still on 2.6.6? Or do you mean 2.10.6?

Comment: Really 2.6.6, 10y old ubuntu. But latest ubuntu has version 2.8.16, but the box it runs on is even older, with less cpu-power and memory. Guess I'll have to upgrade my hardware, too.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better way, but, the way I do it is to:

1. open the script fu console (Filters -> Script Fu -> Console)
2. edit a file (say for example: /Users/jamesanderson/code/scheme/gimp/learn1.scm
3. type: (load "/Users/jamesanderson/code/scheme/gimp/learn1.scm") into the console
4. hit enter
5. edit file for changes
6. keyboard arrow up (to get get the load function call again without typing)
7. hit enter

[image]

[image]

Note this is an extension of my answer based on the comment.  When going beyond the simple proof of concept scripts like the above, its important to know that that console retains state between calls.  So for instance, if we run this scheme script:

```
(define jea-test-img-id nil)

(define (jea-find-test-img)
  (car (gimp-image-list)))
```

and then go to the console and type:

```
jea-test-img-id
```

we get as a result:

```
> jea-test-img-id
()
```

which is good, the script initiated the variable as needed and we see the result.  So var set in script, console retains state change from script.  Now lets change the state in the console:

```
(set! jea-test-img-id (jea-find-test-img))
```

we call a convenience function that grabs the first image ID in the active image list and store it in the variable we previously declared (which was then nil).  Now lets examine the question again:

```
jea-test-img-id
```

then the result:

```
> jea-test-img-id
1
```

so high level: when you are working on a script, create working variables that hold the things you want to work on, like image, pxiels, widths etc then piece by piece get the functions working.  In the end you may collapse it into one clean function once you have the short snippet pieces.

Comment: It works, but I have to get the image argument "by hand", using (myx (vector-ref (cadr (gimp-image-list) 0)) where my function is named myx. I can see the results of (print ...) in the console out.

Comment: Aw, yes, in Python: `image=gimp.image_list()[0]` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run gimp from the command line with the -c flag, messages are printed in the terminal:

```
$ gimp -c myfile.xcf
# run my plugin from the GUI menu
My Plugin-Warning: this is a message
```

Tested with GIMP v2.10.18 see `gimp --help` for more command line options.

Comment: works on Windows too. For me the comand was `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe -c`
Another command window will be opened